# Can SignalR Client in a windows service detect 404

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

Implementing  `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` in a Windows service. All works very well.

As part of my services config file I have the URL to the website that has the hub i will be connecting with. This also works well.

What i am not able to find is a mechanism within the SignalR client that will detect or throw an exception should a 404 code come back from the URL.

I know I can enable tracing and output everything that the client is doing but i cannot find any sort of mechanism that would throw an exception should the client not find a hub at the url provided.

Is there such a mechanism in the signalR client or will i have to first check that the destination url is available before using signalR?

Comment: And what it does instead of throwing the exception in this case?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean your connect your client to non existing hub, and client does not throw exception. What it does instead then?

Comment: It (SignalR) doesn't throw an exception and i can't find a way to make it throw one; the essence of my question. I can verify the issue by enabling tracing but that just dumps our to a writer.

Comment: Are you awaiting starting the connection?